# Не может найти в бд значение переменной sqlite3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, sqlite3

Всем доброго времени суток, не могу понять, почему не может найти значение переменной user_id в бд в функции add_value? В бд 3 столбца: id, balance, date, Все без типов данных. Сам код:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import random
import sqlite3
from config import TOKEN

#Соеденяемся с бд
conn = sqlite3.connect("bot.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Настраиваем бота
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#Функции
def add_value(user_id):
   execute =(f"UPDATE users SET balance = 100 WHERE id = {user_id} ")
   cursor.execute(execute)
   conn.commit()

def user_exists(user_id):
   """Проверяем, есть ли юзер в базе"""
   result = cursor.execute("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?", (user_id,))
   return bool(len(result.fetchall()))

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
   if(not user_exists(message.from_user.username)):
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?)", (message.from_user.username, 0, message.date))
       conn.commit()
       await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Добро пожаловать!\n В этом боте ты можешь зарабаотать свои первые деньги !:)\nЧто бы начать зарабатывать напиши /money")
   elif user_exists(message.from_user.id):
       await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ты уже зарегестрирован!\n В этом боте ты можешь зарабаотать свои первые деньги !:)\nЧто бы начать зарабатывать напиши /money")

@dp.message_handler(commands="money")
async def record(message: types.Message):
   money_int = random.randint(0, 11)
   username = message.from_user.username
   if money_int == 0:
       x = " рублей"
   elif money_int == 1:
       x = " рубль"
   elif money_int in range(2, 5):
       x = " рубля"
   elif money_int in range(5, 11):
       x = " рублей"
   await message.reply(f"Поздравляю!\nТы заработал {money_int}{x}")
   add_value(username)

#Запуск бота
if __name__ == "__main__":
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Сама ошибка:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: (имя пользователя)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

структуру вашей БД не видел, тем не менее...

У вас в функцию передается строка содержащая имя пользователя, а я так понимаю должно быть число - идентификатор. И ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

> UPDATE users SET balance = 100 WHERE id = имя пользователя

И даже если в id у вас строка, в запросе она без кавычек, т.е. `имя пользователя` будет считаться названием столбца.

Далее. Всегда проверяйте типы передаваемых данных, дабы защититься от  [sql инъекций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

```
def add_value(user_id):
    if type(user_id) != int:
        raise NameError('Ой! нам передали не число :(')
    execute =(f"UPDATE users SET balance = 100 WHERE id = {user_id} ")
    cursor.execute(execute)
    conn.commit()
```

И напоследок. sqlite не подходит для многопользовательского применения! Переходите на нормальную СУБД. Иначе ваш бот при одновременных запросах будет лежать трупиком

Comment: Чтобы защититься от sql инъекций в первую очередь нужно не данные проверять, а параметр запроса через параметр execute передавать, а не через f-строку: `cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = 100 WHERE id = ?", (user_id,))`